# Error While Creating Azure SQL Server Failover Group

Tags: azure, failover, azure-sql

I am trying to implement a `failover group` in Azure for my SQL servers but I am getting this error while doing so.

Further, I have question too. I got to know that Secondary Server should not be in the same region, but I am anxious to know **whether it should be in same Resource Group?** I dont know whether the error relates to it.

Appreciate if anybody could help and clarify my question.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Few things required for sql managed instance HA in azure :

- Vnet peering between both regions
- NSG rules allowing traffic
- Both MI instance in same resource group